# multitouch doesn't work on windows phone 8.1 device

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've got real device Nokia Lumia 730 (windows phone 8.1) for testing my game cocos2d-x. And I've discovered multitouch doesn't work.

First of all sample code:

```
auto listener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();

listener->onTouchesBegan = [&](std::vector touches, Event* event){
log("onTouchesBegan: %d", touches.size());
}

listener->onTouchesMoved = [&](std::vector touches, Event* event){
log("onTouchesMoved: %d", touches.size());
}

listener->onTouchesEnded = [&](std::vector touches, Event* event){
log("onTouchesEnded: %d", touches.size());
}

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

No matter how many fingers I'm touching it always says 1.
I ran the same app on Android (samsung galaxy s3) and it's working well.

As I found out there's no need/no way to enable multitouch on windows phone and it's already enabled by default.

Second, I made simple test inside my win8.1-xaml project (didn't test win8.1-universal, can't use it anyway, because of lacking 3rd party libs support like admob):

```
Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;

void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
if (Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
return;
TouchPointCollection pointCollection = e.GetTouchPoints(this);
Debug.WriteLine("points touched: " + pointCollection.Count);
}
```

And this actually works and prints correct values.
So running these 2 pieces of code at the same time produces for example this:

> onTouchesBegan: 1 <-- cocos2d-x part
>
> points touched: 2 <-- c# project part

Cocos thinks there's only one touch, however wp knows there's more (2).

Help!